# Explaining to systemd that /var is symlinked to /home/var

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, mount, systemd

Suppose an installation of Debian unstable, using systemd for init, with two filesystem partitions, `/` and `/home`.  Suppose further that, for reasons to do with the physical disks, I have moved the contents of `/var` to `/home/var` and replaced the `/var` directory with an appropriate symlink.  (Please do not try to talk me out of moving `/var` into the `/home` partition, or turn this into a systemd argument ;-)

With this configuration, it is necessary to inform systemd that any unit which requires anything in `/var` cannot be started until after `/home` is mounted.  The one I know to be broken (as it tries to access a file in `/var/lib` very early in the boot sequence) is `systemd-random-seed.service`, but there could easily be any number of others that I haven't happened to notice yet.

What is the best way to configure the *general rule* that "anything needing something from `/var` cannot be started until after `/home` is mounted"?  I will accept an answer of the form "add `Requires=` and `After=` directives to every single unit file affected" *only if* you can demonstrate that there is no superior alternative.

The version of systemd currently in Debian unstable is 224.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, init cannot really know all by itself which files a given service needs, so "this service uses /var" dependencies still need to be declared somewhere *anyway*.

Of course, that ought to be done by the developers & packagers, not by you. For example, the aforementioned `systemd-random-seed.service` **already has all the necessary dependencies:**

```
$ systemctl cat systemd-random-seed
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-random-seed.service
#  This file is part of systemd.
...
DefaultDependencies=no
RequiresMountsFor=/var/lib/systemd/random-seed
...
```

---

So in your case, the "superior alternative" is to use a *bind mount* in place of the symlink. That will hook naturally into systemd's .mount unit dependencies while providing identical functionality to a symlink otherwise.

That is, if you have a bind mount on `/var`, then all units which already depend on `var.mount` will automatically (indirectly) depend on `home.mount`.

```
# /etc/fstab
/home/var  /var  none  bind  0  0
```

(If that's not acceptable, perhaps compiling a custom systemd version with the dependency hacked in would fulfill your 'requirements' better.)

---

If some of your .service units lack proper dependencies, there *is* another option – you can **turn `/var` into an *automount* using systemd's autofs4 support.**

With automounts, any process trying to access files under /var will block until the filesystem is mounted. So a global 'dependency' is created without having to edit individual service units.

To do this, add the `x-systemd.automount` option into fstab. (Or, if you prefer `var.mount` over fstab, then create a corresponding `var.automount` as well.)

```
# /etc/fstab
/home/var  /var  none  bind,x-systemd.automount  0  0
```

Of course this *again* requires that `/var` be a bind mount rather than a symlink.

Comment: Aha! The possibility of a bind mount occurred to me after I posted this question, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation to indicate whether or not it would work.  I'll accept this after confirming it does work (the computer is in the middle of a very large package install right now).

Comment: Some care needs to be taken with the automount approach: it might work for startup, but it doesn't help at all with ordering the shutdown process...  I think it's only mainly a problem with ordering networked filesystem shutdown; if a local mount fails to stop because it's still in use, then systemd-shutdown is supposed to be able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

More than a year later with the version of systemd (229)now shipping with ubuntu 16.04 there is support in fstab for dependency mounting like this.

so it's as easy as doing this.

```
# /etc/fstab
home/var /var x-systemd.requires=/home,x-systemd.automount,none bind 0 0
```

got the idea from this post
https://copyninja.info/blog/systemd_automount_entry.html